# User Object and Security

Tags: php, security

I'm programming my first user interface with login and account management using PHP and I'm stuck on this issue. I'm just about to finish creating my method in creating new user accounts when a thought hit me about my design.

Here's what happens. When the user attempts to log in, the program takes the string (haven't filtered it yet) and checks to see if the user name and password provided is within the database using the user class I created. If the user is found in the database, the username is encrypted using an algorithm from another class, their credential levels are returned, and both values are stored with the user object on a $_SESSION variable. Another session variable is also created that mimics the value of the credential level stored within the object. Should either be unequal to each other, then the session was tampered.

Now on the user class definition (method list), there are methods that allow for the decode and encoding of the encrypted username; wich brings me to my question. Considering the user object is defined by this class which holds these methods to decode and encode the username, would this be considered a security risk? This class will be the same one used for logging in general users, too so I'm not sure...

Comment: Off topic, but I saw this and got worried a bit: "checks to see if the user name and password provided is within the database" - make sure you're *not* storing plaintext passwords.

Comment: Ohh most definitely not. Password is md5 hashed.

Answer (score 1):

A username is seen as public info, in general.

The only cases I've seen restrictions is if/when you want other to limit seeing a list of your user(name)s.

In general, it's the password that you should be weary of.

Also, in the session you might want to save the user table row id instead of user name (this is so you limit an attacker from knowing who the user actually was).
That said, this is again a minor forethought.

Comment: Well I dont store the user password within the object for that same reason. I only use it as a check on request. That's still ok right?

Comment: I don't understand your notion of "object". The whole concept concerns *cookies* (client-side) and *your database* (server-side). On the client side, people usually store a hash of the password (this is a whole subject in itself). On the server side, you can store both the username and password in the same place (database). Some people save passwords in plain text (**very bad** imho). Others encrypt the passwords (**still bad** imho). The best method would be to store a hash instead.

Comment: Well yeah,
Sorry if I'm not being clear. The password is stored as a md5 hash on the DB already. 
Maybe I am thinking about objects the wrong way. But within my created user object, I am able to do something like this (sorry pressed enter):
Since Username is stored in session and user name is encrypted,
$_SESSION['DAUSER'] = new user(username,password,blah,blah)
$_SESSION['DAUSER']->doLogin()
$realuser = $_SESSION['DAUSER']->getDecryptUserName

My question is at getDecryptUserName if having the method in the same class that is being used to create the user object is a security risk.

Comment: @user716009 - That last sentence pretty much explained it all. As long as you're using it correctly, it shouldn't present a security risk.

Comment: Sorry Chris I've been trying to figure out how to contact you directly since you've been a great help thus far.

Comment: Still not exactly the answer I'm looking for. Which last sentence Chris?

Comment: "My question is at getDecryptUserName if having the method in the same class that is being used to create the user object is a security risk." - This is secure in the sense that when you decode the object back into your class, it's the normal code you defined on the server.

Comment: Ok perfect! :)
I guess for added purposes, I think I'll move the getDecryptUserName method into the security class and have the user class call to that to decrypt the encoded username that is stored within it's object.

Thanks again Chris!

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting passwords is a security risk,  its a clear violation of [CWE-257](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html).  You should be hashing passwords,  and sha256 is a great choice.  Further more,  the only thing that needs to be stored in your session is `$_SESSION['logged_in']=True`.  Storing a username/password in the session is a very bad practice.  The default session handler will store this information in `/tmp/SESSION_ID`.

Comment: Great link, but keep in mind that that covers a recoverable format. There are one way servers out there which can store passwords securely. That said, I do agree that in general, passwords should be hashed. But there *are* cases where the password must be stored somewhere (such as when users are not allowed to change passwords for some reason).